# GIFの開始タイミングと終了タイミングをコントロールするJSのライブラリ

Tags: javascript

GIFの開始タイミングと終了タイミングをJSでコントロールできるライブラリを探しています。

詳細を書かせていただきます。
元になるGIFはサーバ上に存在しており、その開始タイミングと終了タイミングをユーザが指定できる様にしたいです。またその指定した状態でループして表示させたいです。
そのためにgifをコントロールするライブラリを探していましたが、適切な物が見つけられませんでした。

ご存知であれば、教えていただけると助かります。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

libgif-jsという、JavascriptでGifを操作するためのライブラリがちょうどご要望に合致するかと思います。
[buzzfeed/libgif-js: JavaScript GIF parser and player](https://github.com/buzzfeed/libgif-js)

下記の通り、開始フレームと終了フレームの操作もできるようです。

> **play controls**
>
> - play -  Start playing the gif
> - pause - Stop playing the gif
> - move_to(i) -    Move to frame i of the gif
> - move_relative(i) -  Move i frames ahead (or behind if i < 0)
>
> https://github.com/buzzfeed/libgif-js#play-controls

Comment: 御返答ありがとうございます。確かにこのライブラリであれば私のやりたかったことを実現できそうです。ありがとうございました。